# Get data for a funnel using Mixpanel api into Google spread sheet

Tags: api, http, google-sheets, mixpanel

I'm trying to get data for a funnel using Query Saved Report api.[(Link)](https://developer.mixpanel.com/reference/funnels-query) And I'm using Apipheny to export Mixpanel data into Google spread sheet. I'd like to see only conversion rate of funnel by month in my Google spread sheet and I hope it'd be arranged in order of month. (Jan to Dec) Which parameter should I do attach in this api url? I'm marketer so I'm not familiar with those programming code so please consider this. [[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkW0l.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uViaa.png)

I want to extract only conversion rate(%) of funnel in Mixpanel and show them in order by month in Google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a support engineer over at Mixpanel and unfortunately this is currently a product gap in that our Query API doesn't allow you to specify specifically what data to return from a Funnels report. Instead we return the absolute counts, conversion percentages, average time to convert, etc. I'd be happy to file this as a product gap for our team to consider adding parameters to specify exactly what metric you want returned.

In terms of the ordering by month, specifying the unit as 'month' should return the data as monthly buckets. So with the unit set to month you could parse the data returned by the API and only pull conversion percentage and time buckets to display in a Google Sheet. I'm not well versed with Apipheny so I'm not sure if it has the ability to parse JSON for specific data to display in the Google Sheet but it's possible a member of your team could write a script to parse that data from the JSON and outputting as a CSV file for example.